# How to select the last 3 rows but the last one

Tags: sql, iso

```
SELECT doesntmatterwhat
FROM whatever
OFFSET 3 LIMIT 2
```

How would I reproduce this, but WITHOUT using `LIMIT` or `OFFSET` to select the last 3 rows but the last one

Comment: So, the RDBMS is MySQL?

Comment: I'm supposed to only use ISO SQL so the RDBMS does not matter. However, it's postgresql

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like homework

Comment: Actually a challenge we got in class, but you're close ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the solution I was looking for. Thanks for helping though.

```
SELECT  doesntmatterwhat
FROM    whatever
ORDER BY 1
OFFSET  3 ROWS
FETCH   FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: you sure? I think you need a `order by <something>` ?

Comment: Yes indeed, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 2 FROM (
SELECT TOP 3 doesntmatterwhat
FROM whatever
) a
ORDER BY doesntmatterwhat
```

**Not using TOP**

```
SELECT n.doesntmatterwhat
FROM (SELECT n.doesntmatterwhat, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY date DESC) AS sequence
  FROM whatever n
 ) n
WHERE n.sequence>= 2 AND n.sequence<= 3;
```

Comment: Can't use TOP either.